# Why can't I reach and test a mule flow?

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4, anypoint-platform, apikit

I have to work with someone else's code. I downloaded the files and imported the project in Anypoint Studio.

Set all the environment variables and updated the code from 4.2.2 runtime to 4.3.0. Updated all the dependencies and deployed it successfully to local inbuilt runtime.

However I am unable to test the code

The method and url goes like this

POST https://localhost:9095/v1/api/hello

However I get no response. The logger in the main flow before APIKit router doesn't even print anything.

If I give wrong url then the console log throws error

POST https://localhost:9095/v1/ap

I am at my witts end here. Pretty sure the url is correct and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are not providing any details to understand or reproduce the issue, like the flows, APIKit configuration, RAML, complete error messages from the log, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

I set anypoint.platform.gatekeeper=disabled as jvm argument rather than environment variable.

Now the request reaches the flow perfectly.